# Text alignment difficulties

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am new to LaTeX and I have a little problem: [image]

How can I align the "Name Name" to be on the same line with "st.gr FAF", and "Prof Name" to be on the same line with "lect.univ". Right now I have the following:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \Large
\emph{A efectuat:}\\
st.gr. FAF \bigskip

\emph{A verificat:}\\
lect. univ. \bigskip

\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
~
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} {\Large}
{\Large Name Name} \bigskip


{\Large Prof Name}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). I think in this case it would be best to use a `tabular` environment instead of two `minipages`. Also, thanks for providing the relevant code snippets, but it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\hfill` inside the same `minipage`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\Large
\emph{A efectuat:}\\
st.gr. FAF \hfill Name Name\bigskip

\emph{A verificat:}\\
lect. univ. \hfill Prof Name
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise don't use a `minipage` at all

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\Large
\emph{A efectuat:}\\
st.gr. FAF \hfill Name Name\bigskip

\noindent
\emph{A verificat:}\\
lect. univ. \hfill Prof Name

\end{document}
```

Comment: @mayor You're welcome. See the edit: you can even not be using a `minipage` for that.